# ATMs which accept UnionPay IC Card in Berlin

Tags: money, berlin, atms

I am from Hong Kong and hold an HSBC ATM card that supports HSBC ATM network and UnionPay ATM network. I am going to travel to Berlin few week later. I would like to be able to withdraw money through my ATM card in an emergency. It's pity that my bank has recently replaced my ATM card which removed support of the PLUS network (in return for better security through the IC on the card).

The only HSBC division in Berlin is a HSBC Trinkaus branch, which owns no ATM in Germany. Withdrawal through counter is an option but it will be really inconvenient and subject to an extra USD10 surcharge on top of the usual overseas withdrawal surcharge.

Are there any ATM machines which support UnionPay **IC** card?

The UnionPay site provides no information about IC-accepting ATM machines.
(Just as I expected for a mainland China site... It does have that "Search ATM" section, but no information available for Germany.) What it does mention is that Sparkasse and BW Bank support UnionPay network in many of their ATMs. However, the site also says not all machines accept an IC card. Nor does their 'phone number help. I dialed their toll-free line for Hong Kong and I heard no voice after connection.

I have no credit card so linkage of the saving account to a credit card is a no go.

Comment: Anyone can provide some locations of ATMs that supports UnionPay network IC card in Berlin? If no one can provide one, I will go for the "workaround" provided by KH. Lee

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**: OP's banker, HSBC starts to issue the brand new Visa PLUS ATM chip (IC) card since October 2013. The PLUS card will be linked to holder's current (cheque) account so for those only have a saving account, they will need to open current account or upgrade to the integrated account first.

> *This part of the original answer is no longer applicable since October 2013 and only kept for reference.*
>
> HSBC (Hong Kong) has decided to provided ATM cards for PLUS network again [in the next few months](http://thehousenews.com/personal/hsbc-responds-new-atm-card-on-the-way-after-the-summer/), so your best bet is to call the HSBC customer services to see if they can issue the good old PLUS ATM cards to you before your departure.

As an alternative, you may request emergency encashment service from HSBC if you need cash in your trip.

If you have saving accounts in other banks, you may also ask if they have PLUS ATM card. Although my Hang Seng Bank ATM card is using the UnionPay IC chip, there is a statement at the back claims the card could be used in the PLUS network. [Some people also comment that Standard Chartered Bank still stick to the Cirrus / Plus network](http://thehousenews.com/personal/travel-warning-leave-your-hsbc-atm-card-at-home/).

Comment: I am well acknowledge of the HSBC policy. However, I am departing two weeks later and I have no Hang Seng bank account. The "emergency encashment service" is subject to an extra USD10.00 surcharge and this needs to be done over the counter.

Comment: If that's the case, I would start by pushing HSBC, see if a PLUS network ATM card is available soon - even they say "after summer". BTW, if your new UnionPay ATM card still has the magnetic strip, you still have the chance withdraw cash even that ATM / merchant does not accept IC cards - although not 100% guaranteed.

Answer (score 2):

I used my Union Pay (Bank of China) card in the Berliner Sparkasse ATM without any problem.

January 2017.